# Change of basis matrix exercise, find the basis given the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix of basis change from basis $B = \{b_1,b_2\}$ to the basis $C = \{(1,1),(0,2)\}$ is

$$ M =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\2&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Find basis $B$.

Well, here's what I did:

Since $M$ changes from $B$ to $C$, then it Works like this:

$${\begin{bmatrix}& \\\\\\\end{bmatrix}}_C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\2&3\end{bmatrix}{\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}}_B$$

In other words, a vector with coordinates in $C$ is written as the matrix $M$ multiplied by the vector written in $B$.

$${\begin{bmatrix}& \\\\\\\end{bmatrix}}_C = a_1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2\end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\3\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2\end{bmatrix}$and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\3\end{bmatrix}$ are the vectors $b_1,b_2$ written in $C$, so:

$$\vec{b_1} = 1(1,1) + 2(0,2) = (1,5)\\\vec{b_2} = 0(1,1) + 3(0,2) = (0,6)$$

but this is not the answer.

**Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? (instead os just solving in another way)**

Comment: You're wrong: the change of base matrix allows to compute `old` coordinates as linear functions of the `new` coordinates.

Comment: @Bernard sorry, I didn't understand. Shouldn't the matrix $M$ multiply a vector with coordinates in $B$ and transform it to $C$?

Comment: No. It's $M^{-1}$ that does that. Check how it was obtained in your course notes. It can be easier to memorise, if you call $B'$ the `new`base, $X'$ the new coordinates. $M$ is made up of the coordinates of the vectors in the `new basis`, relative to the old basis, but it allows to compute the `old coordinates`from the `new ones`: $ X = M_B^{B'} X'$.

Comment: @Bernard could you write what this matrix multiplies, like I did?

Comment: ...and the above messy comments are one of the reasons why some algebraist **still** write functions on the right of the argument, as well as matrices operating on *row* vectors from the right, etc. But they're now in serious inferiority of number

Comment: @Guerlando OCs: I'll give details in moment.

Comment: @Timbuc: Would you care to explain your comment? I understand there is confusion about which direction to call change of basis from B to C, but this is just a matter of nomenclature. I cannot see how the situation would be different if one wrote matrices on the other side (and they would have to be transposed of course). The relation between change of bases is inverse, not transpose.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen My proffesor, S. Amitsur, *always* used to denote by $\;xT\;$ the application of a map or matrix $\;T\;$ on a vector $\;x\;$ , and in this way he wrote his text book "Algebra". Using this notation, one does *not* have to take the trasnpose of the coefficients' matrix when applying the map on a basis (and writing the outcomes as lin. comb. of another basis), but in fact the direct coeff. matrix. This makes things easier **in this respect** . This is the reason *perhaps* why some denote $\;[T]^{B'}_B\;$ the matrix of $\;T\;$ wrt. to those basis, meaning that...

Comment: ...one applies $\;T\;$ on elements of $\;B\;$ and write the outcomes as lin. comb. of $\;B'\;$, and other is **exactly** the other way around, and then, in the above comments, one gets $\;M\;$ is the passing matrix from $\;B\;$ to $\;C\;$ , and *not* $\;M^{-1}\;$ . Now, this is *still* messy for me and I studied this and understood it very well long years ago, so I guess it can be way messier for beginners. In your comment, you say they'd have to be transposed, and I think it is exactly the other way around: with the usual notation, *it is* the transpoed that's to be taken. Hope this explains.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen And as you can see, the very first answer below (Bernard's) denotes the change matrix $\;P_B^{B'}\;$ , **with** $\;B\;$ the old one, in disagreement with the notation used by others. It is just a matter of convention, yet it makes lots of problems in first years at universities.

Comment: @Timbuc: I don't understand anything of what you are saying. But the following is a fact, independent of how one writes coordinate vectors and matrices. In $\Bbb R^2$, if apart from the standard basis $B$ you consider the ordered basis $C=[(2,0),(0,2)]$, then transforming a vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ w.r.t. $B$ into coordinates w.r.t. $C$ gives $(x/2,y/2)$. Traditionally one calls the matrix $P=2I$ with the coordinates of $C$ the change of basis matrix (from $B$ to $C$). Converting $(x,y)\to(x/2,y/2)$ by **left or right** matrix multiplication requires the _inverse_ matrix $P^{-1}$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen See? Even to someone with experience it is hard to explain, and grab, in this reduced form. My main point is that what some write as $$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&3\end{pmatrix}\binom11=\binom25=b$$my professor, and others, would write$$x^tA^t=(1\;1)\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&3\end{pmatrix}=(2\;5)=b^t$$ Observe that the matrices above are transposed of each others and I've taken as "regular" vectors the column ones. The outcome is exactly the same, though...but ordered slightly differently.

Comment: @Timbuc: Yes, I know this and it is exactly what I meant in my first comment. The point is that in the end everything is the same, just written differently. In particular it **does not change** the fact that given the coordinates of a new basis, one needs to compute the inverse of a matrix in order to transform coordinates to that new basis. The two issues are quite unrelated, so changing conventions on one issue does not solve anything for the other issue.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen This is pretty confusing: all the time I thought the main issue (of the OP, at last) was the notation, and I tried to address this...I've to think about how to convey this more properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

- First remember the change of basis matrix $P_\mathcal B^{\mathcal B'}$ from an `old base` $\mathcal B$  of a vector space $ E $ to a `new base` $\mathcal B\,' $ has as column-vectors the coordinates of the `newbase` in the `oldbase`. It is the matrix of the `identity map` from $ (E, \mathcal B\,') $ to $ (E, \mathcal B) $.
- The change of basis matrix the other way is just the inverse matrix of the previous one: $$P_{\mathcal B'}^{\mathcal B}=\bigl(P_\mathcal B^{\mathcal B'}\bigr)^{-1}$$
- It allows to express the `old coordinates` $X$ of a vector from the `new coordinates` $X'$: $$X=P_\mathcal B^{\mathcal B'}X'$$
- You can compose the change of basis matrix:
  $$ P_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B''} = P_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B’}P_{\mathcal B’}^{\mathcal B''}$$

Denote the canonical base as $\mathrm{Can}$. Determining $\mathcal B$ is the same as determining  $P_{\mathrm{Can}}^{\mathcal B}$. By the composition formula, we have:
$$P_{\mathrm{Can}}^{\mathcal B}=P_{\mathrm{Can}}^{\mathcal C}P_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal B}=P_{\mathrm{Can}}^{\mathcal C}\bigl(P_{\mathcal B }^{\mathcal C}\bigr)^{-1}.$$

Now $ P_{\mathrm{Can}}^{\mathcal C}=  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\1&2\end{bmatrix} $, and we compute with the pivot method that 
$$\bigl(P_{\mathcal B }^{\mathcal C}\bigr)^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\2&3\vphantom{\tfrac 13}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\-\tfrac23& \tfrac 13\end{bmatrix}$$
so that $$P_{\mathrm{Can}}^{\mathcal B}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\-\tfrac 13& \tfrac 23\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence $b_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\-\tfrac 13\end{bmatrix}$,  $\quad b_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\tfrac 23\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Why the hell it's named "from $B$ to $B'$", if when we multiply this matrix by the vector $X'$ we end up in the basis $B$, not $B'$? Why 'from $B$ to $B'$'???

Comment: Probably because most of the time, it's the vectors of the basis $\mathcal B'$ which are given. Anyway, if you don't understand that, you'll never understand the formulae for the matrix of a linear or bilinear map on a change of basis.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the matrix $M$ to the basis vectors in $B = \{b_1=(a,b),b_2=(c,d)\}$ and note that

> $$M b_1^T = (1,1)^T \longrightarrow (1) $$
>
> $$M b_2^T = (0,2)^T \longrightarrow (2) $$

then solve the resulting system in $\left\{ a, b, c, d \right\}$. Note that you can solve $(1)$ for $a$ and $b$ and $(2)$ for $c$ and $d$ separately.

Comment: I don't even know what your notation means, I'm so lost

Comment: You do not know what the transpose $u^T$ of a vector $u$!

Comment: I mean, I don't know why you're multiplying the matrix. I'm lost with the part of 'change from $B$ to $C$'

Comment: You are asked to find the vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$ so we need to assume them as $b_1=(a,b)$ and $b_2=(c,d)$. Note that the Matrix $M$ maps the vector $b_1=(a,b)$ to the vector $(1,1)$ and same for $b_2=(c,d)$. Now just take your time to work the problem out.

Comment: Nice, I understand what you're doing. It's because I was following my book. According to the construction the book made, the matrix first column should be $b_1$ written in terms of $C$. The same for the second column. Then, if I have $b_1$ and $b_2$ written in $C$, I should solve for $b_1$ and $b_2$, rigth?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: The technique I gave you solves the problem from scratch. You do not have to memorize things just try to understand. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I'm gonna post my answer for future readers. 
 I think you are right as a matter of fact.
Let **M** be the change of basis matrix from base **B** to base **C**.
 
Let **[v]<sub>B</sub>** be the coordinate vector of some vector **v** with respect to basis **B**, 
let **[v]<sub>C</sub>** be the coordinate vector of that same vector **v** with respect to basis **C**.
By definition **M****[v]<sub>B</sub>** = **[v]<sub>C</sub>** 
Now let **B** = {**b<sub>1</sub>**,...,**b<sub>n</sub>** },
 the coordinate vector of any **b<sub>i</sub>** with respect to **B** is simply **e<sub>i</sub>**,
 from the standard basis: 
 $$\mathbf{[b_i]}_B = \mathbf{e}_i =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ .\\.\\.\\1\\.\\.\\.\\0\\\end{bmatrix}$$ where 1 is the i-th coordinate.
Now, as you may know, the product between any matrix **A** and **e<sub>i</sub>** gives back **A<sup>i</sup>** (the i-th column of **A**), 
 We can use these facts to arrive to the following conclusion: 
 **M****[b<sub>i</sub>]<sub>B</sub>** = **[b<sub>i</sub>]<sub>C</sub>** = **M<sup>i</sup>**,
 hence in your particular case we can infer that  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{[b_1]}_C $$ 
 
 $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\3\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{[b_2]}_C $$ 
 Therefore: $$(1)\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} + (2) \begin{bmatrix} 0\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\5\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf {b_1}  $$ 
$$(0)\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} + (3) \begin{bmatrix} 0\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\6\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf {b_2}  $$