# Change of basis matrix for polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

I've understood what a change of basis matrix is, and how it's structured.

So a change of basis matrix from $B$ to $C$ is the matrix $M$ such that:

$${\begin{bmatrix} &\\ \\ \\\end{bmatrix}}_B = {\begin{bmatrix} &&&&\\ \\ \\\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix} &\\ \\ \\\end{bmatrix}}_C$$

or

$$[v]_b = M[v]_c$$

However, my book extends this concept to polynomials. I see no problem if I see the polynomial $1+2t^2+3t^3$ as the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\\\end{bmatrix}$ and then I can constructo such matrix. But the exercise asks the following:

> The change of basis matrix from the base $B=\{1+t,1-t^2\}$ to the base
>   $C$ is
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find basis $C$

So basically we have this structure:

$${\begin{bmatrix} &\\ \\ \\\end{bmatrix}}_B = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}{\begin{bmatrix} &\\ \\ \\\end{bmatrix}}_C$$

where the first column vector is $[b_1]_c$  (vector $b_1$ written in terms of base $C$) and the second is $[b_2]_c$. So in some way I should find the basis $C$, but since there's a $t^2$ term, a '3 dimensional' vector should appear somewhere. How do I proceed?

Comment: You probably remembered the wrong definition? I think it should be the other way. $[\quad]_C=[\quad ][\quad ]_B$. In that case it is easy to find.

Comment: @KittyL in my book "from $B$ to $C$" means what I written

Comment: the vector space of polynomials of degree less or equal to 3 is a vector space of dimension 4.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs check your textbook again.  A change in basis from $B$ to $C$ takes **as its input** a coordinate vector with respect to $B$ and gives **as its output** a coordinate vector with respect to $C$.  Hence, it goes "from" $B$ "to" $C$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom omg i can't understand it, days ago they said the opposite to me: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090382/change-of-basis-matrix-exercise-find-the-basis-given-the-matrix

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Mhenni's take on things mirrors my own, but Bernard seems to disagree.  I stand by my point.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Or perhaps not... I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the way you said makes much more sense, and thats how I first though about this, but then my book said that the other way is the correct one, but it makes less sense.

Comment: It doesn't matter in principle which one you take to be the "change of basis matrix", as they are just inverses of each other. I've seen it defined both ways. For this exercise, you'll definitely want to know what your book means by "the change of basis matrix from B to C."

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The nomenclature for change of basis matrices is a known point of confusion. At least here in France it is standard to say the change of basis from $B$ to $C$ changes coordinates w.r.t. $C$ into coordinates w.r.t. $B$, which indeed seems the wrong way. But in practice one usually wants to change to $C$ after finding the coordinates of the vectors of $C$ (for instance eigenvectors) w.r.t. the basis $B$; it would be annoying to have to say each time that this gives the columns of the _inverse_ base change of the one that one wants to apply (even if in the end both will be needed).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$.  Then $A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}&-\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$ is the change of basis matrix from C to B, so

$w_1=\frac{1}{3}(1+t)+\frac{1}{3}(1-t^2)=-\frac{1}{3}t^2+\frac{1}{3}t+\frac{2}{3}$ and

$w_2=\frac{2}{3}(1+t)-\frac{1}{3}(1-t^2)=\frac{1}{3}t^2+\frac{2}{3}t+\frac{1}{3}$ are the basis vectors in C.

(Notice that B and C are bases for a 2-dimensional subspace of the 3-dimensional vector space of polynomials of degree at most 2.)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what book you are using I cannot comment on the correctness of the approach used there. Nevertheless, whatever approach is used, care must be taken about what precise relationship one is using to reason about these things. There are, at least, two equivalent ways of viewing this: 1) in "implicit" terms of **coordinate changes** and 2) in "explicit" terms of **how the bases vectors, themselves, are related**.

Perhaps I can make this clear with an example. For a finite-dimensional vector space, the **coordinates** of a vector $\,\,\vec{x}\,\,$ *w.r.t.* two given bases can be used to define a change of coordinates from one basis to another. So, for example, **if** :

i) The coordinates of $\,\,\vec{x}\,\,$ *w.r.t.* to the bases $B$ and $C$ are $\left(\begin{array}{c}x^B_1 \\ x^B_2\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}x^C_1 \\ x^C_2\end{array}\right)$ respectively,

ii) The $B$ basis vectors have coordinates $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}2 \\ -1\end{array}\right)$ *w.r.t.* to the $C$ basis vectors,

**then**, the change of *coordinates* **from** $B$ **to** $C$ is given by

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x^C_1 \\ x^C_2\end{array}\right){}={}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x^B_1 \\ x^B_2\end{array}\right)\,\,\,\,\,\ldots\,(*)
$$

However, suppose we were to, instead, explicitly represent each $B$ basis vector (say $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$) in terms of the $C$ basis vectors (say $\vec{w}_1$ and $\vec{w}_2$). We can do this using matrix notation as well, so that, unlike (*), we now have

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\vec{v}_1 \\ \vec{v}_2\end{array}\right){}={}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\vec{w}_1 \\ \vec{w}_2\end{array}\right)\,\,\,\,\,\ldots\,(**)
$$

In passing, I should say that this kind of matrix representation is, in part, a convenient shorthand: matrices define linear relationships, in this case the explicit linear relationship between the underlying bases vectors. Now, observe that the matrix representation  in (**) also characterizes what happens to a vector under a change of basis from $B$ to $C$, since for our arbitrary vector $\,\,\vec{x}\,,\,$ it implies we have

$$
\vec{x}{}={}\left(x^B_1, x^B_1\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\vec{v}_1 \\ \vec{v}_2\end{array}\right){}={}\left(x^B_1, x^B_1\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\vec{w}_1 \\ \vec{w}_2\end{array}\right)\,;
$$
that is, starting with a "$B$"-representation of $\,\,\vec{x},\,\,$ we can find the unique $C$-representation of  $\,\,\vec{x}$.

**Note**: The transformation matrix in (*) is between coordinates, while that in (**) is between the underlying bases vectors. Also, note that one matrix is the transpose of the other. And, finally, in either case, to obtain the reverse transformation from $C$ to $B$, one simply inverts the respective matrix (safe in the knowledge that the answers will also be the transpose of each other). In your question, if the given matrix represents a "coordinate" transformation (in the sense I have illustrated), then its inverse is

$$
\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right)\,.
$$